# Understand Javascript callback using simple example

Tags: javascript, callback

I am playing with Facebook SDK. My goal is to learn more Javascript as I play with the example.
Way how I learn is by giving my self tasks, and when I accompish them, I learned it :)

Code that includes Facebook SDK is up and running and is not included here. My question is not aimed toward Facebook API, it is just an example. I am trying to extend my Javascript knowledge with this common problem with callbacks

There is one task that I fail to accomplish, and I assume it is related to callback... 
TASK:
Click a button with this code:

```
<button id="askme" onclick='askFaceBook();'>Direct</button>
```

That code will run the following function:

```
  function askFaceBook() {
         var result = myApi.getLoggedName("Samsung");
     };
```

Which in turn will run the myApi object:

```
var myApi = {
         getLoggedName: function (statement) {
             return FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                 console.log(response);
                 return response + "" + statement;
             });
         }
     }
```

PROBLEM:
Variable result is always undefined. It is executed before myAPI.getLoggedName is returned. myAPI is working as expected How do I make variable result wait for the result. I know I could use promises/deffered, but I want to understand and learn how to do it Javascript style using callback.

I hope someone can help me with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first whats wrong with return statement in myApi.getLoggedName

Function FB.api is taking two argument out of which second is your callback reference and there is no use of return statement in callback as no one expects a return value from a callback. So when you called FB.api then it just registers that callback (which gets executed on the response) and returned nothing and hence your function myApi.getLoggedName returned undefined.

Now how to fix this

In these kind of scenarios we can use Promises like

```
var myApi = {
    getLoggedName: function (statement) {
       var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                resolve(response + "" + statement);
            });
       }).then(function(result) {
           return result;
       });
    }
 }
```

Now in this case the then lock will be executed when resolve is the promise gets called and it will pass the result as an argument in then callback. I this case result wont be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

When you're calling your `myApi.getLoggedName()` and assigning it's result value to `result`, that value will be instantly assinged. However, since the api call is asynchronous, the return value will be `undefined`. You thus need to assign the value *after* the async call has finished. One way of doing this is using a callback function, like this:

```js
var myApi = {
  getLoggedName: function(statement, callback) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      if(typeof callback === "function") {
        callback(response);
      }
    });
  }
}
function askFaceBook() {
  var result;
  myApi.getLoggedName("samsung", function(response) {
    result = response;
    console.log(result); // => actual result
  });
  console.log(result); // => undefined, because async hasn't finished yet!
}
```

Comment: What a great example!!! It cleared my mind regarding callback a bit. Is there more examples like this?

Comment: @DonaldM Check out [José Romaniello's article](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) on jQuery.Deferred and Promise for an alternative to callbacks.

Comment: I cant get it to work.when the myApi.getLoggedName is executed, the inner function FB.api is getting callback as undefined

Comment: WHen the FB.api returns, the callback value is undefined